# How to test a Humio parser without actually emitting logs

Tags: logging

My application has its logs sent to Humio using some Kubernetes magic which I'm not in charge of.

According to [the Humio docs](https://docs.humio.com/docs/parsers/built-in-parsers/#json) if the log line contains JSON this will be parsed by Humio by default.

I'd like to test the log lines which my application emits to see that they are parsed correctly by Humio but to test it I'd have to deploy my application to production in order for its logs to be written to Humio.

Is there a way I can test my log output against Humio's parsers without deploying my app to production?

There's no mention of testing anywhere in the Humio docs.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a good use for [the `sandbox` repo](https://docs.humio.com/training/foundational-concepts/the-sandbox/) which every user gets by default.

You can use [the CLI](https://docs.humio.com/reference/cli/#getting-started) to send data to Humio, even just by typing directly into the terminal:

```sh
$ humioctl ingest
2021/06/01 15:40:29 Humio Attached to StdIn, Forwarding to 'sandbox'
Hello world
Hello world
```

Anything you write there will show up in your Sandbox repo and you can check the parsing of log rows there.

If you're writing logs to be parsed by a particular Humio parser, the simplest way to specify a parser is to do it on the command-line.

You can also pipe the output of your app directly into Humio which is pretty nice:

```sh
./my-log-emitting-app | humioctl ingest --parser json
```

Answer (score 0):

You can paste test lines in on the right pane of the [Parser Editor](https://library.humio.com/stable/docs/parsers/creating-a-parser/), then test how the parser ingests those lines.